# PHP5 - Remove value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which has some date like

```
[1] - HELLO
[2] - BYE
[3] - SEE
[4] - DISABLED_HEY
```

I want now to remove every value in the array which begins with DISABLED

My follow code only works when I enter the full text like DISABLED_HEY

```
$sites = array_diff($sites, array('DISABLED'));
```

What I have to do that it works more generic? (I tried it with asterisk but this didn't help).

Comment: [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) may be of use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($item) {
    return strpos($item, 'DISABLED') !== 0;
});
```